# How can I change the value of a querystring with mooTools?

Tags: javascript, mootools, query-string

Given a string containing an absolute URL with a querystring parameter, what is the easiest way to replace the value of the parameter using JavaScript and/or MooTools?

e.g.

```
// Change this
'/foo/bar?frob=123456789'

// Into this
'/foo/bar?frob=abcdefg'
```

**EDIT**

The URL is not the `location` of the current window. It is a variable containing a string. I just want to manipulate this string.

Comment: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/String.QueryString though if manipulated as string, this is hardly to do with any library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for bumping an old post but I think it's already in mootools. No need to write it yourself :-) http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/URI#URI:setData

Or take a look here if your on a very old version of mootools: http://pilon.nl/mootools/2009/02/05/extra-browsersextras/

Answer (score 3):

Further to what you did, this may be better as it will extend `String` and it removes dependency on URI class...

```
(function() {

// deps on Types/String.toQueryString()
String.implement({

    fixQueryString: function(key, value) {
        var query = this.parseQueryString() || {};
        query[key] = value;
        return Object.toQueryString(query);
    }

});

// exports:
this.replaceUrlParameter = function(url, key, value) {
    var parts = url.split('?'), QS = parts[1] || null;

    return QS ? [parts[0], QS.fixQueryString(key, value)].join("?") : url;
};

})();

console.log(replaceUrlParameter('/foo/bar', 'frob', 'ownies'));
/foo/bar/
console.log(replaceUrlParameter('/foo/bar?frob=123123123', 'frob', 'ownies'));
/foo/bar?frob=ownies
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/fjj6W/

Comment: Nice answer, concise but also contains more than the bare minimum of information!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do this without reloading the page, there is no way (this is part of the web browser security model).
If You don't mind reloading the page, consider:

```
location.href='http://example.com/foo/bar?frob=baz'
```

An alternative without reloading is using location.hash, i.e.

```
location.hash = 'myhash'
```

to change url to http://example.com/foo/bar?frob=123456789#myhash

This is the basis of the [Hash bang urls](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. This is dependent on MooTools.

```
function replaceUrlParameter (url, parameterName, newValue) {
    var uri = new URI(url);
    var uriBase = ri.get('directory') + uri.get('file');
    var query = uri.get('query').parseQueryString(false, true);
    query[parameterName] = newValue;

    uriBase += '?';
    for (var i in query) {
        if (i === 'undefined') continue;
        if (i === '') continue;
        uriBase += i + '=' + escape(query[i]) + '&';
    }
    return uriBase.substring(0, galleryLinkBase.length - 1);
}
```

This is specific to my usage but it might serve as a starting point for others in the future.